# Symfony save date for every change status

Tags: symfony, doctrine

how i can to do this: I have OrderWork entity this for order and have relation manyToMany with Status entity. All work good, but i want have date for every saved and updated order.

```
   * Order
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_work")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\OrderWorkRepository")
 */
class OrderWork
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderNumber", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $orderNumber;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderCity", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $orderCity;

    /**
     * @var date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderDate", type="string", length=255, options={"default": NULL})
     */
    private $orderDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="returnDate", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $returnDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="device", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $device;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SurrogatePhone", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="surrogate_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $surrogatePhone;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="orderType", type="integer")
     */
    public $orderType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="order_status",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)}
     *      )
     */

    private $status;
```

How better resolve this solution?

Comment: Can you clarify you question. Are you saying you want $date to be updated whenever you persist your OrderWork entity? Also, is there a reason that $date is a string?

Comment: Check out [Doctrine extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/common_extensions.html)

Comment: Yes, i want save $date for relation $status, that when i get status i will se when this status updated.

Comment: I changed date to datetime

Comment: why not using timestamp in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Define date in your constructor (for creating):

```
class OrderWork
{
    //...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new DateTime();
    }

}
```

And update date field when updating:

```
$orderWork->setDate(new DateTime());
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I need date for status field, for history updated status.

Comment: And how to do when i updated OrderWork but status not changed, i want that his if insert duplicated, update.